# C# User Control - How to tell containing object the control needs data

Tags: c#, user-controls

I am creating a C# WinForms user control. There will be times when the user control will need data from the form it's contained in. How do I go about having the user control tell the form containing it that it needs some data?

Thanks!

Comment: Good question; yet I don't see a need for a usercontrol if it needs data from its containing control. Usercontrols shouldn't be used in this case. You shouldn't code this kind of logic inside of a usercontrol.

Comment: @Pabuc - Since you have no idea what my user control is doing, your statement is meaningless.

Comment: I'm with Pabuc. I can't see your User Control but it sounds like you might be violating Separation of Concerns. I wonder if there's a small redesign that would solve this problem.

Comment: What should one use instead? For example I have a paginator, which renders links. I have an object which generates the hyperlink objects which need to be rendered out by the ascx template. User controls seems like a DRY way to put pagination on to a page without a whole bunch of binding going on. In an MVC framework I would just use some kind of template inheritance, but apparently I cannot do this in asp.net webforms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subscribe the form to an event raised on the UserControl.

Your archiecture dictates where and when you need to subscribe to the data event.  We can't answer that without knowing a little more about how your whether you are adding the control at runtime or design time.  Each case will require a little derivation.  From the perspective of adding your control at runtime, you could do something similar to the following:

```
// Your sample control
public class MyUserControl : Control
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> INeedData;
    public Data Data {get; set;}

    private class DoSomething()
    {
        if(INeedData!=null) INeedData(this,null);
    }
}

...

// Your Form, in the case that the control isn't already added.
var _myUserControl = new MyUserControl();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _myUserControl.INeedData += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(MyUserControl_INeedData);
    this.Controls.Add(myUserControl);
}

void MyUserControl_INeedData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _myUserControl.Data = SomeData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an event on the user control where the event args are editable. Let the form attach a handler to that event, which updates those fields. Use those fields in the OnEvent method.

[untested]
eg.

```
public delegate void NeedsUserDataEventHandler(object sender, NeedsUserDataEventArgs args);

public class NeedsUserDataEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public UserData UserData { get; set; }
}

// In Control
public event NeedsUserDataEventHandler NeedsUserData;

public void OnNeedsUserData(NeedsUserDataEventArgs args)
{
    NeedsUserDataEventHandler handler = NeedsUserData;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, args);
    // store your data somewhere here
}

// In Form
public override void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    control.NeedsUserData += ControlNeedsUserData;
}

public override void OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    control.NeedsUserData -= ControlNeedsUserData;
}

public void ControlNeedsUserData (object sender, NeedsUserDataEventArgs args)
{
    args.UserData = // set whatever here
}
```

Comment: Then when another control comes along that needs the data you need to go back to your object and register another handler...bah...make the one who cares about the data register for it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom event in the user control and have the form hook into it.  If you need custom event arguments, you can create those too.

In user control:

```
//Define your Custom Event argument
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    //Define some fields of your custom event argument
    private int m_SomeValue = 0;

    //Define some properties of your custom event argument
    public int SomeValue
    {
        get { return m_SomeValue; }
        set { m_SomeValue = value; }
    }
}

//Define the event handler data type
public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e);

//Define the object which holds the outside event handlers
public event MyEventHandler SomeEvent;

//Define the function which will generate the event
public virtual void OnSomeEvent(MyEventArgs e)
{
    if (SomeEvent != null)
        SomeEvent(this, e);
}

.
. //Then later in the control
.
{
    //We need new data

    //Create the event arguments
    MyEventArgs newEvent = new MyEventArgs();

    //Set the values
    newEvent.SomeValue = 17;

    //Call the event generating function
    OnSomeEvent(newEvent);
}
```

In your form just use something like:

```
myControl.SomeEvent += new MyEventHandler(handlerName);
```

Since your event is public, you should see it in the Properties window of your control as well.

You can fancy up the event using Metadata attributes, but I leave it up to you to discover these.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit vague to me, but:

Make it an event in the containing WinForm, so that every time some data is ready all the subscribers can be notified in a one-to-many model; or make it an event in the subscribed control, in a one-to-one model, in which it calls the container's method that retrieves such data?

Comment: OP - this is the Observer Pattern.  Google it, this may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's dependent on when that data needs to be pushed to the UserControl. Are there events taking place on the Form that will drive the need to move data within the UserControl? If so...simply grab your instance at that point and push the data down to the UserControl via a public property.

If this is a case where events are not being used or the Form in some fashion or another "receives the data" then exposing an [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28VS.71%29.aspx) on the Form such as...

```
public event DataHandler ReceivedData;
```

...and allow the UserControl or any other container to register for the event and receive the data via your custom event args. Pushing the event into the UserControl and forcing the Form to latch onto the UserControl seems backwards since the Form is the initiator of the data.

Comment: Disagree. Putting the event on the Form and having the user control attach to it is dangerous because the order of cleanup will be confusing. You can easily end up with circular references that allow neither to be disposed. Very difficult to debug that kind of memory leak.

Comment: @pdr Because it is confusing it makes it wrong? Hmm...the Form in this case (it could be any object) is the object behind the data. If other objects want data from this Form they should also have the ability to subscribe to the event and receive the data. Forcing the Form to latch on to each and every object when he is the one raising the data has no merit.

Comment: I am not saying the approach is "wrong", I'm saying it is dangerous. However, the last sentence in your answer is plain wrong.

Comment: @pdr How is it plain wrong? Why would you have the initiator of the data be the one subscribing to events on varying objects throughout your application? You don't have events on your object and force a Button to subscribe to your object to let you know he has been clicked...how is this any different?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow your example. But I can think of no scenarios offhand where I would expect a child object to subscribe to an event on the parent (where child/parent is defined as the parent encapsulating the child). This is why we have the Observer Pattern